# Запуск функции при нажатии на кнопку в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Как в aiogram при нажатии на кнопку, вызывать функцию.
Сейчас имеется такой код :

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, ' Привет {0.first_name}', reply_markup=kb_main)
```

При нажатии на старт , появляется меню, и вместо названия кнопок, у меня идут названия команд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при нажатии на ту или иную кнопку, срабатывают команды, там как вместо текста идет прямое название команды.

Как сделать так, чтобы название кнопок было любое, но при нажатии на ту или иную кнопку, вызывалась нужная команда?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть если я нажал на Test1 ( кнопку ) , чтобы функция /test1 сразу запустилась, а не вывелась в чат.

на примере вот такого метода

```
async def bot_text(message: types.Message):
if message.text == 'Test1':
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '/Test1')
```

Answer (score 0):

При создании кнопки вы можете указать `callback_data`, который будет связан с этой кнопкой:

```py
command = CallbackData('function')
button = InlineKeyboardButton('Любое', callback_data=command.new(function='test'))
```

Для обработки вам понадобится `callback_query_handler`:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(command.filter(function='test'))
async def test(query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    pass
```

Comment: спасибо большое, получается данный метод применяется только в инлайн кнопкам?

Comment: @Stock Да, параметр `callback_data` доступен только для `InlineKeyboardButton`. Но если вы хотите изменить название для обычных кнопок, ничего не мешает вам это сделать. Пока что не понимаю вашу проблему

Comment: Название для обычных кнопок я изменить могу. Но при нажатии на них в чате отображается название кнопки. А я хочу чтобы при нажатии запускалась функция нужная. Так как у меня каждая функция находится в раных файлах .py , то я не могу понять , как при нажатии на кнопку ,вызывать функцию из других файлов. https://imgur.com/ykNt5sF вот так я могу отловить текст и далее не пойму как через if запустить функцию из другого файла. Можно конечно указать код функции прямо в этом коде ( на скрине )  , но учитывая что функций много , не удобно все это помещать в этот код.

Comment: https://imgur.com/IWYtG7z Вот на скриншоте , постарался детальнее описать, то что хочу получить.

Comment: @Stock Так просто переименуйте кнопку. Например, в  `Ping`. И в обработчике замените условие: `if message.text == 'Ping'`. Бот будет отвечать `/Test1`, но кнопка уже будет называться `Ping`

Comment: я так и сделал. Далее если я нажимаю на кнопку Ping , то в чате получаю просто текст /Test1, а не запуск функции /Test1

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2pLg.png вот выше скидывал. тут я нажал на кнопку Test1, в ответ получил название функции /Test1 , то есть просто название , сама функция она не запустилась .

Comment: @Stock Всё верно. Вы же просто отправляете сообщение с текстом `/Test1`, вы другие функции не вызываете. Вот и получаете просто сообщение. Предположим, вы хотите вызвать функцию с именем `func`, тогда добавьте в тело условия вызов: `func()`

Comment: а если я кнопку назову сразу командой например /Ping
то в таком случае, сразу запускается функция. Вот  я и ищу решение , чтобы кнопка имела одно название а при нажатии запускалась команда и чтобы не пришлось в if message.text == *** вставлять код от каждой функции.  Сейчас попробую через импорт модуля с функцией и ее вызов . Либо буду изучать инлайн кнопки и переписывать под них . Спасибо еще раз.